# Form Show not Called After Second Show

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So I am using Visual Basic to create a windows form application. I have buttons on the side to select a table [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqKDN.png). When the 'bookings' button is pressed, the user it taken to a form that looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E7cF.png). I need the following code to run every time the form is shown (the form is hidden shown multiple times). I put the below code inside both the form load and the form shown actions and both of them will only run the code on the first time. The code isn't really relevant, I just need to know how I can make this run every time the form is shown, not just once. The only other way I have thought about which works is to make the code run every second which is just unnecessary and a waste of processing power. Also, if I wanted another action to run after this, the action that occurs every second will take priority.

```
 Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    If GlobalVariables.GlobalFlag = "1" Then
        Table1Sleep.Visible = False
        Table1Selected.Visible = True
        Table1Selected.BringToFront()
        table1text.BringToFront()
        table1textdesc.BringToFront()
    ElseIf GlobalVariables.GlobalFlag = "2" Then
        Table2Sleep.Visible = False
        Table2Selected.Visible = True
        Table2Selected.BringToFront()
        table2textdesc.BringToFront()
        table2text.BringToFront()

    ElseIf GlobalVariables.GlobalFlag = "3" Then
        Table3Sleep.Visible = False
        Table3Selected.Visible = True
        Table3Selected.BringToFront()
        table3text.BringToFront()
        table3textdesc.BringToFront()
    ElseIf GlobalVariables.GlobalFlag = "4" Then
        Table4Selected.Visible = True
        Table4Selected.BringToFront()
        tabel4text.BringToFront()
        table4textdesc.BringToFront()
        table4sleep.Visible = False
    ElseIf GlobalVariables.GlobalFlag = "5" Then
        Table5Selected.Visible = True
        table5sleep.Visible = False
        Table5Selected.BringToFront()
        table5text.BringToFront()
        table5textdesc.BringToFront()
    ElseIf GlobalVariables.GlobalFlag = "6" Then
        table6sleep.Visible = False
        Table6Selected.Visible = True
        Table6Selected.BringToFront()
        table6text.BringToFront()
        table6textdesc.BringToFront()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong. When you press 'OK', you will be taken back to the Main Menu.")
        MainMenuForm.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Try the `Activated` event.

Comment: Using a tab control would be a lot easier. For true form shown event to ire each time you'll have to make sure you Hide() the form in between Show() (hide it when the user clicks ok)